# Bash -Handle double quotes in variable

Tags: bash, variables

I am Declaring  a variable

```
var1="D:\TEMP\scripts\test.sh"

echo var1

output:
D:\TEMP\scripts\test.sh
```

I would like to get the value from var1  and assign to another variable var2 and if I do a echo var2, I should be getting the outting

```
echo var2

Expected output:
"D:\TEMP\scripts\test.sh"
```

Comment: If you assign, why would you get different outputs? Also, `echo var1` only echoes `var1`, not the output you claim.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry ..I got this already. Thought it would be difficult.

```
[user@server ~]$ var1="D:\TEMP\scripts\test.sh"
[user@server ~]$ echo $var1
D:\TEMP\scripts\test.sh
[user@server ~]$ var2=\"$var1\"
[user@server ~]$ echo $var2
"D:\TEMP\scripts\test.sh"
[user@server ~]$
```

Comment: You may want `var2="\"$var1\""` to prevent `$var1` value to be split on space. Also consider that just leading and trailing `"` to the value, will fail when value contains `"` already.

Comment: While you may have legitimate cases where you need to output a dbl-quoted value, your example doesn't make that clear. In any case, You'll do better to get in the habit of always dbl-quoting any (almost) usage of a variable, i.e. `echo "$var"`. Not correctly quoting variable usage is the number one beginners problem in writing shell script. Best to work your way thru https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls to avoid the top 10 problems. Good luck.

Comment: @LéaGris The right-hand side of an assignment isn't subject to word-splitting. There's also no interference between literal quotes in the assignment and any literal quotes in the value of the parameter expansion.`var1='"'` and `var2=\"$var1\"` has the same result as `var2='"""'`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to escape the quotes inside the quotes of variable; try this:

```
var1="\"D:\TEMP\scripts\test.sh\""
var2=$var1
echo $var2
```

output:

```
"D:\TEMP\scripts\test.sh"
```